# Error creating bean with name 'baseController': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring

> Error creating bean with name 'baseController': Invocation of init
> method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:160)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsBeforeInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:416)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1788)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:595)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:517)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:323)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:321)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:879)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:878)
> at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:702)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:668)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:716)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:591)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:530)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:170)
> at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:158)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.initServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1143)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.loadServlet(StandardWrapper.java:1090)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapper.load(StandardWrapper.java:984)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.loadOnStartup(StandardContext.java:4891)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5202)
> at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1412)
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1402)
> at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
> Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
> at DiamondShop.Service.User.HomeServiceIml.GetDataMenus(HomeServiceIml.java:33)
> at DiamondShop.Controller.User.BaseController.Initial(BaseController.java:19)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleElement.invoke(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:389)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$LifecycleMetadata.invokeInitMethods(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:333)
> at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessBeforeInitialization(InitDestroyAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:157)
> ... 30 more

---

```
    @Controller
    public class BaseController {
        
        @Autowired
        HomeServiceIml _homeService;
        public ModelAndView _mvShare = new ModelAndView();
        
        @PostConstruct
        public ModelAndView Init () {
            _mvShare.addObject("menus", _homeService.GetDataMenus());
            return _mvShare;
        }
    }
```

---

```
@Controller
public class HomeController extends BaseController{

    
    @RequestMapping(value = {"/","/trang-chu"} )
    public ModelAndView Index() {
        
        ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("user/index");
        mv.addObject("slides", _homeService.GetDataSlide());
        mv.addObject("categorys", _homeService.GetDataCategorys());
        return mv;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping(value = "/product")
    public ModelAndView Product() {
        
        ModelAndView mv= new ModelAndView("user/product");
        return mv;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey! Could you please add more details? What is the problem? When does it occur?

Answer (score 0):

A method annotated with @PostConstruct should not have any return value!
For further information have a look here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javax/annotation/PostConstruct.html

> The method defined on a non-interceptor class MUST HAVE the following signature:
> void ()
> The method on which PostConstruct is applied MAY be public, protected, package private or private.
> The method MUST NOT be static except for the application client.
> The method MAY be final.
> If the method throws an unchecked exception the class MUST NOT be put into service except in the case of EJBs where the EJB can handle exceptions and even recover from them.

A typical use-case can be found here: https://www.baeldung.com/spring-postconstruct-predestroy